# Error on filter: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

I'm create app with recycler view and search interface

Whatever i do, i receive this error

PostAdapter filter interface

```
public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                String charString = charSequence.toString();
                if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                    contactListFiltered = questionList;
                } else {
                    List<Posts> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (Posts row : questionList) {

                        if (row.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase()) || row.getExcerpt().contains(charSequence)) {
                            filteredList.add(row);
                        }
                    }

                    contactListFiltered = filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = contactListFiltered;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                contactListFiltered = (ArrayList<Posts>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
```

questionList and contactListFiltered it's a `List<Posts>`

Search interface

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
     ListFragment listFragment = new ListFragment();
     PostAdapter postAdapter = new 
     PostAdapter(listFragment.mPosts,getApplicationContext(),false,false);
     postAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
     return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
      ListFragment listFragment = new ListFragment();
      PostAdapter postAdapter = new 
      PostAdapter(listFragment.mPosts,getApplicationContext(),false,false);
      postAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
      return true;
}
```

Debug seen error on this line

```
if (charString.isEmpty()) {
```

[image]

Comment: How do you initialize `questionList`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question, try additionally check charString on null

```
if (charString == null || charString.isEmpty()) {
```

Comment: Error now on this line ```for (Posts row : questionList) {```

Comment: It shouldn't go to that line, if there's null. In this case Filter must return null.